# Constraining a newtype parameter

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Having a following custom newtype:

```
newtype QueryM a = QueryM (Connection -> IO a)
```

How can I declare an `Alternative` instance for it while constraining the `a` to have `Alternative` instance too? Or can I?

I mean something like this:

```
instance (Alternative a) => Alternative (QueryM a) where
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Did you even try?

Comment: @melpomene Well, the compiler doesn't agree with you )

Comment: ... but you're not going to show us the error message?

Comment: @melpomene `Expecting one more argument to 'a'   In the instance declaration for 'Alternative (QueryM a)'`. If I add an argument it blames a kind mismatch expecting `* -> *` but getting a `*` from `QueryM (a b)`

Comment: Are you sure you want Alternative, not Monoid? What's it for? Could you give an example of an instance you'd want to make?

Comment: @AndrewC `QueryM` wraps a query to a db, I wanted to be able to chain several of those with `<|>` based on wether the query returns an `empty` result.

Comment: Thanks. That's much clearer. What would an example of the type `a` be?

Comment: @AndrewC A list or a maybe of a type having an instance of [FromRow](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/postgresql-simple/0.2.4.1/doc/html/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#t:FromRow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiles fine here if I add an argument to `a`:

```
import Control.Applicative

newtype QueryM a b = QueryM (Connection -> IO (a b))

type Connection = ()

instance Functor (QueryM a)
instance Applicative (QueryM a)

instance (Alternative a) => Alternative (QueryM a) where
```

Comment: Thanks! What do those bodyless instance declarations actually do? The compiler throws warnings, but still compiles.

Comment: When there's no default definition for a method, it'll just be replaced with an error. Not recommended for real code.